# I'm having trouble sending two strings in one SMS in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm trying to send a SMS when a button is clicked in my app. I want it to send a text, and then in  another line send my GPS location. I already got it to send the GPS location, but I can't add the other string I want. My code looks like this:

```
                double lat = l.getLatitude();
                double lon = l.getLongitude();
                String info = "This is the string I want to send in my sms!";
                String message="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+lat+","+lon;
                String number = "xxxxxxx";
                StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
                smsBody.append(Uri.parse(message));
                android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, smsBody.toString(), null,null);`
```

This is only sending the URL with the GPS location, but I tried adding the text and the URL to the same string, and it didn't work, in two sepparate strings and concatenate them and didn't work either. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concat this message because lat e lon are Double, must convert it to String.
example:

```
String latString = String.valueOf(lat);
String lonString = String.valueOf(lon);
```

and after use latString and lonString to cancat message

or in a simple way:

```
String message="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+String.valueOf(lat)+","+String.valueOf(lon);
```

for send SMS you can use this function:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg) {
try {      
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);    
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 
}
```

Comment: I did that but still isn't working. I modified the message like this: String message="other string"+"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latString+","+lonString;

Comment: It just doesn't send the sms

Comment: This works, but it  requires user interaction. I need the SMS to send automatically. I tried changing the ACTION_VIEW to ACTION_SENDTO but it doesn't send automatically either. Do you know how can I do this with your code?